# Filter RDD by values PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I'm using PySpark and I'm looking for a way to check :

For a given check_number = 01

if the value of the third element in my `rdd1` do not contains check_number
==> get all informations about this check_number from `rdd2`..

Given :

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(u'_guid_F361IeVTC8Q0kckDRw7iOJCe64ELpRmMKQgESgf-uEE=',
                        u'serviceXXX',
                        u'testAB_02',
                        u'2016-07-03')])
```

Supposing that the first element is an `ID`, the second is a service name, the third is a test name, with an `ID`, and the fourth element is a date.

```
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([(u'9b023b8233c242c09b93506942002e0a',
                        u'01',
                        u'2016-11-02'),

                       (u'XXXX52547412558933nnBlmquhdyhM',
                        u'02',
                        u'2016-11-04')])
```

Supposing that the first element is an ID, the second is a test id, and the last element is a date.

So, here I have in my `rdd1` `testAB_02`, which does not match with my check_number (so the service name must ends with check_number's value). My object if is to get all rows from `rdd2`, with `01` as test id. The expected output here must be :

```
[(u'9b023b8233c242c09b93506942002e0a',
  u'01',
  u'2016-11-02')
```

This is my code :

```
def update_typesdecohorte_table(rdd1, rdd2):

    if rdd1.filter(lambda x : (re.match('.*?' + check_number, x[2]))).isEmpty() is True:

        new_rdd2 = rdd2.filter(lambda x : x[1] == check_number)

    else:

         pass

    return new_rdd2

new_rdd2 = update_typesdecohorte_table(rdd1, rdd2)
```

Wich gives :

```
[(u'9b023b8233c242c09b93506942002e0a', u'01', u'2016-11-02')]
```

This code works, but I don't like the method.. What is the most efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all records from rdd2 that have no matching elements in rdd1 you can use `cartesian`:

```
new_rdd2 = rdd1.cartesian(rdd2)
    .filter(lambda r: not r[0][2].endswith(r[1][1]))
    .map(lambda r: r[1])
```

If your check_number is fixed, at the end filter by this value:

```
new_rdd2.filter(lambda r: r[1] == check_number).collect()
```

But if your check_number is fixed and both RDDs are large it cen be even slower than yours solution as it needs shuffling over partitions during join (your code performs only non-shuffling transformations).

Comment: Thx Mariusz ! This is what I want, and the method seems robust !